# x is divided by y but not partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

One of the problems in my discrete math course says:
Let $x,y \in \mathbb N-\{0\}$. $(x,y) \in D$ iff  $x$ divides $y$ or $y$ divides $x$. The problems asks whether this is a partial order or not and the answer is that it's not. The only way this would be true is if $x \neq y$. Are we supposed to assume that $x \neq y$? Because if $x=y$ then this should be a partial order because it's reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the relation $D$ is made for *any* pair of positive integers. You must not assume that $x=y$ or that $x\neq y$.

$D$ is not a partial order because it is not transitive. A relation is not transitive when there is at least *one* conterexample. That is, to show that $D$ is not transitive, you only need to find two pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ in $D$ such that $(x,z)$ is not in $D$.

$(3,6)$ and $(6,2)$ are in $D$, but $(3,2)$ is not.

Comment: Gotcha! The fact that it's not transitive this is the reason. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a good example for your intuition.  If we just asked that $x$ divide $y$ you would have a partial order.  When we put the "or $y$ divides $x$" we lose the idea of order.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's transitive? Think about the sequence $2, 6, 3$ . . .

Also, it's not antisymmetric: $(2, 6)$ and $(6,2)$ are both in $D$.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly symmetric, the definition itself is symmetric.

Comment: but it says x divided by y OR y divided by x. If we have x=2 and y=4, then y is divided by x without remainder which satisfies  the second part of OR.

Comment: @Yos That's not relevant to symmetry: do you see why **both** $(2, 4)$ and $(4, 2)$ are in $D$? Do you see why that's a problem?

Comment: Yes you're right. It's symmetric which makes it not partial order